# Call jquery plugin on app load and on every state change in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS app I want to call:

```
$('.nano').nanoScroller({ alwaysVisible: true });
```

When the app loads, and then when the state changes.

For non-angular apps I would do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nano').nanoScroller({ alwaysVisible: true });
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('.nano').nanoScroller({ alwaysVisible: true });
});
```

I've looked at using a directive:

```
.directive('nanoScoller', function() {
  return {
    $('.nano').nanoScroller({ alwaysVisible: true });
  };
});
```

But how would I call that in the same way as above?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code on route/state change.

If you are using angular router, you can run this on $routeChangeSuccess. More in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)